# Specifying default value for django hidden form field - bone DRY?

Tags: django, django-forms, dry, django-queryset

So let's say at the last minute (in the view) I decide I want to specify a default for a field and make it hidden, like so:

```
form.fields['coconut'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    label="", 
    widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
    queryset=swallow.coconuts.all(),
    initial=some_particular_coconut,
)
```

My question is this:  Do I really need to specify queryset here?  I mean, I already know, from initial, exactly which coconut I'm talking about.  Why do I also need to specify that the universe of available coconuts is the set of coconuts which this particular swallow carried (by the husk)?

Is there a way I can refrain from specifying queryset?  Simply omitting causes django to raise TypeError.

If indeed it is required, isn't this a bit damp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to set up a hidden ModelChoiceField. In order to have a Choice (dropdown, traditionally) it needs to know its Choices - this is why you give a queryset.

But you're not trying to give the user a choice, right? It's a hidden input, and you're setting it from the server (so it gets POSTed back, presumably).

My suggestion is to try to find a way around using the hidden input at all. I find them a bit hacky. But otherwise, why not just specify a text field with `some_particular_coconut.id`, and hide that? The model's only wrapping that id anyway.

Comment: I'm into that, and I also thought that it was a bit hacky.  But what's the convention here?  There are some cases where a session can suffice, but let's suppose this isn't one of those.  What then?  What are some of the main techniques?

Comment: Well, I'm a fan of sessions, but if you have a busy webapp I understand how you'd like to avoid them. It sounds like you're trying to "bounce" an object off the browser into another view... why exactly are you trying to do that? I'd say the above technique is the best way to do that particular thing, but there may be more elegant ways of doing whatever operation you're trying to do...

Answer (score 12):

I think is good that stackoverflow answers point to the 'right' way to do things, but increasingly the original question goes unanswered because the user was trying to do the wrong thing.
So to answer this question directly this is what you can do:

```
form.fields['coconut'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="", widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'value':some_particular_coconut}), queryset=swallow.coconuts.all())
```

Notice the named argument passed to HiddenInput, its super hackish but its a direct answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason django requires a queryset is because when you render the field to the page, django only sends the id. when it comes back, it needs knowlege of the queryset in order to re-inflate that object.
if you already know the queryset at form creation time, why not simply specify `form.fields['coconut'].initial = some_particular_coconut` in your view and leave the rest of the definition in your forms.py?

If you find that you only really need to send the id anyway (you don't have to re-inflate to an object at your end), why not send it in a char field?

Comment: But this still doesn't make DRY sense - if it has an integer, and the field is a foreign key, what's the difference in the end?  In other words, it *always* expects an integer as the field value where the foreign key has an integer PK.

Comment: django knows it's a ForeignKey from the model.  On the other end, I'm just doing EuropeanSwallowForm(request.POST).  Coconut has a ForeignKey to EuropeanSwallow.  In the handler view, django has no idea that I ever made the field hidden in the interim.